# Creating a way to copy sheets from a .xlsm file to a .xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba, saving-data

I am trying to copy sheets from a macro enabled Excel file (.xlsm) to a non-macro enabled file (.xlsx).
I believe that some change have been recently made to Excel that is preventing using the process I used before: *Include in the a VBA code that saves the ".xlsm" as ".xlsx" the following instruction: "Application.DisplayAlerts = False"*.

I tried the following process (and it almost worked!):

1. Create an empty non-macro enabled file (.xlsx).
2. Open the macro enabled file (.xlsm).
3. Select the sheets to copy from the macro enabled file (left click the sheet tab of one sheet to select it and then "shift + left click" on the others).
4. Right click on the tab selected first. This opens a small window with some options.
5. On the small window left click on "Move or Copy" option. This opens a new small window.
6. On the bottom of new window select the box at left of "Create a copy".
7. On the "To book" at the top of the new window select the ".xlsx" file.
8. Click "OK" button, (sheets are copied to the ".xlsx" file).

I was unable to save the non-macro enabled file, created by the above process, because an error window popped up with four buttons: "Save", "Save and erase features", "Go back" and "Help". The previous method "*Application.DisplayAlerts = False*" no longer worked.

Code triggered by activeX controls were copied to the ".xlsx" file, as well.
I solved this problem by removing sheets that had elements like: buttons, activeX controls, etc.
Then I could save the ".xlsx" file.
I will have to restructure, or get rid of, some code that are triggered by activeX controls.

But, some links to the ".xlsm" file were created in the ".xlsx" file. I was unable to understand the reason.

[image]

## **I do not know how, *and ask help on*, to avoid the creation of links to the ".xlsm" file on the ".xlsx" file.**

Comment: "an error window popped up with four buttons" Did that window mention what error it was reporting, or it just had those 4 buttons?

Comment: The window did not mention what error it was reporting. I created a screenshot of the popup where you can perceive what the error was. (https://t.ly/Z0eKu).
Thanks for any help.

Comment: No there was no mention to the kind of error it was. The link shows a capture of the error window (https://t.ly/Z0eKu)

Comment: I have the same problem with some of my clients, we have a xlsm file that processes some data and finally saves the file as xlsx in a different folder.
earlier the save prompt when saving as non-macro workbook would have 3 options: "yes", "no" and "help" with yes as default meaning we save and discard code, but now the prompt is having 4 options with "back" as the default and hence the vba code fails

so how do we get the old prompt version back?

Comment: @Martin, you text describes my problem! I decided to change my approach and instead of trying to save the ".xlsm" as a ".xlsx", I redeveloped a new VBA code that copies the ranges I need from the ".xlsm" and paste them to a previously created and saved".xlsx" template. After some debugging I was able to complete the task.
However, I am still facing the problem with the undesired copy of links from the ".xlsm". An I am unable to avoid this.

Comment: @pandre45, wow, I wouldn't know where to start if I should copy all sheets to a new workbook, this one has several sheets (10+), many with queries to databases, some hidden etc. that would be an insurmountable task for me, but I'm glad it works for you.
in the meantime, one of the users no longer has this problem, I assume due to some update of Excel/Office, it just annoys me that there is no documentation of this prompt

Comment: @Martin I did it and it works OK. It was easier than I expected. I had some hurdles and it took some effort (specially copying formulas and crafting the template). I learned a lot.